# How do I make a string from javascript appear in the html when certain checkboxes are clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

So i want too start off by saying I am very new at web development, specifically javascript. I'm trying to build a simple program where you check certain items from a list of certain ingredients from a video game, and you are then told which recipes you can make. I am struggling with getting the text to appear in the html when a box is checked.

This is my html for one of the ingredients that make a recipe from just the one item:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="egg" name="egg">
  <label for="egg">Egg</label>
    </div>
```

This is the javascript I have trying to make the recipe appear under the checkboxes in a paragraph with the id being "make":

```
if (document.getElementById("egg").checked === true) {
    document.getElementById("make").innerHTML = "You can make a fried egg with egg!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I hope you find some useful answers here!

It looks like you're trying to alter the rendered HTML on a page when a checkbox is clicked.

The problem with the fragment above is that it's run only once, and you probably need to listen to events.

Events are a whole new world for a new dev -- but don't worry, you got this!

Basically, events are signals that stuff happened. So you need a piece of code to fire when the checkbox was clicked. If you're using native JavaScript, that might be something like this:

```js
const el = document.getElementById("egg");
el.addEventListener("click", ev => {
  const message = el.checked
    ? "You can make a fried egg with egg!"
    : "You can't make fried eggs at all!";
  document.getElementById("make").innerHTML = message;
});
```

Now, every time the "egg" element is clicked, that code above is run, updating the inner html of the "make" element.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you'd need to put an event listener (just a usual function) on your checkbox that would process every change of the input's value and, depending on whether this value is `true` or `false` you can update the value of your output.

You can run the code snippet and see the implementation details.

```js
function updateResult(checkbox) {
  const make = document.getElementById("make");
  make.innerHTML = checkbox.checked === true 
    ? "You can make a fried egg with egg!"
    : "";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="egg" name="egg" onchange="updateResult(this);">
  <label for="egg">Egg</label>
</div>
<div id="make"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost on the right track. However, the will run only once (and immediately), thereby giving no results. For this "`bind`" an event listener. This will make sure that every time the checkbox is *clicked*, a function you define is executed. Like so -

```js
const check_box = document.getElementById("egg");

// this function decides what message to set and shows it
function cbClicked(event){
  let message = "";
  //check if box checked
  if(check_box.checked) {
    message = "You can make a fried egg with egg!";
  }
  //box not checked
  else {
    message = "You can't make fried eggs at all!";
  }
  //set message
  document.getElementById("make").innerHTML = message;
}

//add an eventlistener by telling what 'even' to listen for
// and what function to run
check_box.addEventListener("click", cbClicked);
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="egg" name="egg">
  <label for="egg">Egg</label>
</div>
<div id="make"></div>
```

Notice how I passed a function as an argument to `.addEventListener()` , that's possible and also completely normal. The passed function is called a *callback function*. You can even define it entirely **inside** the  `.addEventListener()` in which case you don't even need to set a name for that function like so-

```
.addEventListener('event_name',function(event){
//body of function
})
```

The first argument `event` is the event that occurred which is automatically passed by the event handler. I didn't use it here though.